# Convert Tuple of list to dataframe

Tags: python

Quick question! I want to convert Tuple of list to df, also with index name.

Like this

tt = ([0.094, 0.233, 0.088],
[0.979, 1.4, 0.953 ])

I hope it shows

```
      Apple Banana Pizza
mean  0.094  0.023  0.088
std   0.979  1.4   0.953
```

mean and std are row names.

I know there are lots talking about list of tuple to df, but I didn't find tuple of list to df. (or maybe I miss it...)

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make a difference between list of list or tuple of list. Did you try it?

Comment: try, ``pd.DataFrame(tt, index=['mean', 'std'], columns=['Apple', 'Banna', 'Pizza'])`` ?

Comment: Oh, okay! Let me try it

Answer (score 0):

Is this right answer for your question?
Do you want to get other solutions without pandas package?

```
import pandas as pd 
tt = ([0.094, 0.233, 0.088], [0.979, 1.4, 0.953 ])
df = pd.DataFrame(tt, index=['mean', 'std'], columns=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pizza'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'd like to learn more about other solution!

Comment: There is no need to convert tuple into a list, as tuple is a iterable.

Comment: Yes, the second line is unnecessary

Comment: @sushanth you're right!, so just express the procedure getting list from tuple.

Comment: Could you correct the answer? Because it mentioned **the suggested edit queue is full**. Thanks